# How do you consume the latest message from Kafka topic?

Tags: javascript, kafkajs

I'm using KaafkaJS to connect and consume the kafka messsages.
I'm using the following code to consume messages. But it fetches all the messages but I would like to store the last message in the variable `messageValue`. Can someone help me with it please.

```
await consumer.run({ 
            eachMessage: async (data) => {
                    messageValue = data.message.value.toString('utf8').trim()
            }
        })
console.log(messageValue)
```

Comment: You might want to try eachBatch instead of eachMessage.

Comment: eachBatch giving error to call

Comment: Does this help?
https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#a-name-each-batch-a-eachbatch

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add fromBeggining: false

https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#a-name-from-beginning-a-frombeginning

Answer (score 0):

This below code worked for me. [Reference](https://www.sohamkamani.com/nodejs/working-with-kafka/#creating-the-kafka-consumer)

```
const consume = async () => {
    await consumer.connect()
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic, fromBeginning: true })
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: ({ message }) => { 
            console.log(`received message: ${message.value}`)
        },
    })
}
```